# How to reconfigure keyboard input toggle shortcut

Tags: 16.04, lts, input-language, input-method

I have been trying to set a shortcut for changing between input languages and at some point a window popped up that asked me to set that shortcut. After that whenever I use that key to toggle it only changes from English to my local language and doesn't change back to English if I pressed it again. I think something went wrong during the download and install of adding the second language and setting a shortcut for it. Is there a way to download and reinstall these settings all over again?

Edit: Running the snippet `cat /etc/default/keyboard` outputs:
 XKBLAYOUT=us,ir 
BACKSPACE=guess 
XKBVARIANT=,pes_keypad

Comment: What shortcut key are you trying to set?

Comment: I have set right alt key.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what the command `cat /etc/default/keyboard` outputs.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Done.

Comment: That file does not include any option for switching keyboard layout. What kind of desktop environment are you on? Ubuntu with Unity or some flavor?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I'm sorry I don't exactly understand your question. I have installed it on my PC desktop and the file I installed said it was Ubuntu LTS 16.04 I think. I think when it was downloading the files necessary to add my local input, my internet stopped working currectly for some time and it installed some corrupt version of the input methods. Can't I just reinstall these files?

Comment: The files for keyboard layouts are installed to begin with. But, since you are on Ubuntu, please let us know the output of this command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson It says `['grp:toggle', 'grp_led:scroll']`.

Comment: Then, to clean it up, you can run this command: `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Okay, the shortcut is disabled now. What should I do to re-enable it properly this time? Last time I just stumbled upon some option to do it. Removing and adding Persian input again doesn't seem to let me set a shortcut key, either.

Comment: The default shortcut for switching layout is <Super>+<Space>. If you want something else, use System Settings.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thank you so much sir. Please add your answers in the answer section so that others who have the same problem can use this info. I can do it for you if you want as well.

Comment: Please do so yourself. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. Then, in a couple of days, you'll be able to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point that I had missing was that by default you could have switched between input languages by using the combination `Super`+`Space`; but if you somehow did something that ruined this shortcut, you can run the command `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` to erase the new settings and it's now back to default. If you want to use any new combination you can set it through the settings menu.

***All credits go to @GunnarHjalmarsson for helping me out through this.***